How can I align the median labels across the 4 levels of my geom_point?
I've added median lines to my geom_point and asked to attach labels to the right of them via hjust = -1.5. However, the label of the fourth level is misaligned, sitting a lot further to the right of the median line. I suspect this has something to do with the size of the figure relative to the other single digit figures. How can I correct this so that all labels are equidistant from their corresponding median lines?
ggplot(UK_12wk1, aes(x = experiment_flag, y = Message_numbers_3m)) +
    geom_point(cex = 1.5, pch = 1.0, position = position_jitter(w = 0.1, h =0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) +
    stat_summary(fun = 'median', aes(colour = "median"), geom = "crossbar", width = 0.4) +
    stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,2)), fun = 'median', geom = 'label', size = 4, hjust = -1.5)      +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Control", "Reactive text", "Reactive premium", "Proactive")) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed', color = "blue") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "italic", vjust = 0.65),             axis.ticks.x =     element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16), legend.title = element_text(size = 16),    plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold")) +
     labs(x = "Group", y = "Messages sent", color = NULL) 



One option would be to move the label to the left of the red median lines using hjust=1.5.
stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,2)), 
             fun='median', geom='label', size=4, hjust=1.5)


Another option is to use sprintf instead of round to make the size of the labels more similar. This also gives more consistency to the values displayed.
stat_summary(aes(label=sprintf("%.2f", ..y..)), 
             fun='median', geom='label', size=4, hjust=-0.5)



Data:
UK_12wk1 <- structure(list(experiment_flag = c("Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", "Reactive text", 
"Reactive text", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", 
"Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Reactive premium", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", 
"Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive", "Proactive"), Message_numbers_3m = c(10, 
1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 
2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 5, 0, 6, 1, 5, 19, 5, 10, 0, 10, 1, 7, 10, 
5, 7, 0, 5, 7, 8, 0, 11, 1, 8, 3, 7, 4, 10, 2, 13, 5, 6, 5, 11, 
2, 12, 11, 6, 1, 8, 0, 12, 11, 0, 1, 7, 17, 4, 8, 8, 1, 16, 6, 
6, 2, 1, 4, 13, 7, 6, 14, 3, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 13, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
5, 7, 14, 5, 5, 13, 2, 7, 10, 3, 16, 6, 9, 16, 6, 19, 19, 16, 
8, 3, 3, 3, 6, 18, 7, 23, 10, 8, 11, 9, 11, 17, 10, 27, 8, 18, 
19, 6, 5, 8, 10, 8, 9, 2, 8, 6, 3, 6, 3, 9, 7, 10.1124, 13.69, 
8.2369, 14.7456, 9.7344, 7.84, 12.4609, 14.0625, 18.7489, 6.6564, 
24.3049, 19.0096, 21.16, 25.5025, 14.2884, 9.4249, 5.3824, 4.9729, 
16.3216, 19.0969, 13.2496, 13.1044, 16.4025, 7.5076, 25.3009, 
14.5161, 11.56, 18.5761, 10.3041, 25.8064, 16.6464, 16.3216, 
13.5424, 11.1556, 7.8961, 2.7889, 7.4529, 25.2004, 5.1529, 19.7136, 
22.5625, 23.04, 12.8881, 9.7344, 19.4481, 16.9744, 17.9776, 25.4016, 
8.7616, 4.3264)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -200L
))

